# How do I embed a PDF into my template with Django?

Tags: python, html, django, web-applications

I am trying to embed a user manual into a template and thought this would work, but it did not. Is it my file path? I will attach a photo of where I have the PDF stored.

HTML:

```
<div class = "container">
    <embed src= "Users/remio/mis446-2/mis446/blog/templates/mis446/files/User-Manual.pdf#toolbar=0" type= "application/pdf" width= "100%" height= "600px"/>
  </div>
```

Views.py:

```
def user_manual(request):
    return render(request, 'mis446/user-manual.html')
```

urls.py:

```
 path('user-manual/', views.user_manual, name='User Manual'),
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qxsO.png)
It is in the file called "files"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the pdf in your static directory and then use the following.

```
{% load static %} 
<iframe src="{% static 'pdf/User-Manual.pdf' %}" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
```

You'll have to put the `User-Manual.pdf` into `static/pdf`.

Comment: Maybe I'm not putting them in the right place, but that isn't working for me. What do you mean by put them in my static directory?

Comment: Nevermind! I moved it to the right place. Thank you so much for your help!